# How should I configure lot4net inside app.config?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

My application uses a little logging library I created that in turn uses log4net.  I have been passing the bare name of a configuration file to my library, and the library's Initialize() method calls ConfigureAndWatch(configFileName.xml).  The application can run as a service.  When it does, I don't know what its working folder is, so I don't know where to put the configuration file.  I don't want to have to use an absolute path name for the configuration file.  Instead, I'd rather put the log4net configuration inside my app.config file.

So, I put this inside my AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

And here is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="RunType" value="Console"/>
    <add key="DSNName" value="Hot Spot Control"/>
    <add key="LoopTime" value="10"/>
    <add key="WriteSetpointToPlcInfo" value="True"/>
  </appSettings>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="TimedFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:/misc/HotspotControlService.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="TimedFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I am not getting any logging.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  I tried the simple example in [this page](http://spencerooni.github.io/2016/05/06/simple-log4net-setup.html), and it worked.  So I think my problem is that I am trying to use a little logging wrapper in a separate assembly from my main program.  I tried putting the new line in that assembly's AssemblyInfo.cs file, but it didn't work.

Comment: _"When it does, I don't know what its working folder is"_ - why not? _"What am I doing wrong?"_ - does the service account have permissions to write in that folder?

Comment: What is the default working folder that a service uses?  I don't know.

Comment: The working folder doesn't matter for the .exe.config, it just needs to sit beside the executable.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  That's why I'm trying to move configuration into app.config.  My first setup, in which I specified the configuration file in a call to ConfigureAndWatch("MyConfigurationFile.config") inside my program, was what I was talking about.  When running as a service, the program will look for MyConfigurationFile.config in the current working folder, and I don't know what the current working folder of a service is.